# Add multiple accounts to PHP message script

Tags: php

I'm having a login system with a "special message for" system. Only the user called `johndoe` will see that message.

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == 'johndoe' ) {
echo "<p>You have a message, just for you!</p>";
} else {
echo "<p>You have no messages, you're a loner. Just kidding.</p>';
}
```

How can I make it so I can also add `janedoe`, so they both see the same message?

Comment: Just create an array with the users, which should see the message and then check with `in_array()`, if the current user is in the array

Comment: You can check like this: 
`if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['username'] == 'johndoe' || $_SESSION['username'] == 'janedoe' ) )`

Comment: @hrskrs Thanks, that works. Can you add your comment to answers so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: @MateDontHateJustSkate your question is `marked as duplicate`, so thats not possible

Comment: @Rizier123 yo rizier I know you love me but technically this isn't an duplicate

Comment: @MateDontHateJustSkate Why not, didn't it solved your problem? The dupe is exactly what your looking for.

Comment: @Rizier123 ya you're right, but I just hate that yellowish box under my post ya know